# How to overlay an image from a select div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

How do I get another image to overlay onto my selected `<option>`? Here is my code so far, but I struggle to keep the `.Lines` over the base. I have my reason for wanting to keep them separated as this is practice for a future project. However, I am stuck trying to keep my overlay line image from disappearing completely when I select an option from my list of bases.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#BunnyBase").change(function () {
        var src = $(this).val();
        $("#imagePreview").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");
    });
});
```

```css
.BunnyBase {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.Lines {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <center>
        <div>
            <select name="BunnyBase" id="BunnyBase" class="inputbox" size="1">
                <option value=""> - Select Image - </option>
                <option class="BunnyBase" id="WhiteBase" value="https://i.ibb.co/mbtB0zD/White-Base.png">White</option>
                <option value="https://i.ibb.co/C6XHVh2/BlueBase.png">Blue</option>
                <option id="BlackBase" value="https://i.ibb.co/mz2yGC3/Black-Base.png">Black</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="imagePreview">
            <div>
                <img class="Lines" id="Lines" value="https://i.ibb.co/gFYphBy/MaleThin.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
```

Comment: did my answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional div for a static image with an outline by changing the jiquery code and css with the participation of this div. In my example, this is a div with a class of `circuit_img`.

Set the width of the images to rule `width: 100%` by adding this to your css:

```
#imagePreview img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

The main problem with your code is the incorrect use of method `html()`. This method replaces the entire html in the specified selector, which means that when you first select a color image, you overwrite your image with an outline. To avoid this, make two different divs with pictures, as in my example:

```
<div class="colors_img"></div>
<div class="circuit_img"></div>
```

Also, for a picture with an outline, use attribute `src` instead of `value`.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#BunnyBase").change(function () {
        var src = $(this).val();
        $("#imagePreview .colors_img").html(src ? "<img src='" + src + "'>" : "");
    });
});
```

```css
.BunnyBase {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    z-index: 1;
}

#imagePreview {
    position: relative;
}

#imagePreview img {
    width: 100%;
}

.circuit_img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <center>
        <div>
            <select name="BunnyBase" id="BunnyBase" class="inputbox" size="1">
                <option value=""> - Select Image - </option>
                <option class="BunnyBase" id="WhiteBase" value="https://i.ibb.co/mbtB0zD/White-Base.png">White</option>
                <option value="https://i.ibb.co/C6XHVh2/BlueBase.png">Blue</option>
                <option id="BlackBase" value="https://i.ibb.co/mz2yGC3/Black-Base.png">Black</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="imagePreview">
            <div class="colors_img"></div>
            <div class="circuit_img">
                <img class="Lines" id="Lines" src="https://i.ibb.co/gFYphBy/MaleThin.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
```